# Unable to centre social footer

Tags: html, css

I am seeing a strange issue where social footer icons are not centering? This is code I have inherited and just need someone else's pair of eyes to see if they know how to set the icons to be displayed in the center:

Code:

```css
body { background-color: black }
```

```html
<div class="socialfooter" style="padding-bottom: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px; text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
  <p>
    <a style="float: left; margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.instagram.com/balancecoffee" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Instagramwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
    <a style="float: left; margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.facebook.com/balancecoffee20" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Facebookwhite.svg" width="29px" height="29px"></a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a style="float: left; margin-right: 12px;" href="https://twitter.com/BalanceCoffeeUK" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Twitterwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a style="float: left; margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.pinterest.com/balancecoffee" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Pinterestwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

How it looks at the moment:

[image]

Comment: this probably depends from the container css and its css but cannot see either in the question

Comment: I made you a snippet. You need to show the container and its CSS and not float the links

Comment: Ah ok, I will go grab the container, give me a moment

Comment: If you float something it can't be centered. Use flexbox for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `float: left` on the links that is causing them to, well, actually float to the left, and change the paragraphs to `display: inline-block;`

```css
body { background-color: black }

.socialfooter p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="socialfooter" style="padding-bottom: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px; text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
  <p>
    <a style="margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.instagram.com/balancecoffee" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Instagramwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
    <a style="margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.facebook.com/balancecoffee20" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Facebookwhite.svg" width="29px" height="29px"></a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a style="margin-right: 12px;" href="https://twitter.com/BalanceCoffeeUK" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Twitterwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a style="margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.pinterest.com/balancecoffee" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Pinterestwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

to the `.socialfooter` class

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.socialfooter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="socialfooter" style="padding-bottom: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px; text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
  <p>
    <a style="float: left; margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.instagram.com/balancecoffee" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Instagramwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
    <a style="float: left; margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.facebook.com/balancecoffee20" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Facebookwhite.svg" width="29px" height="29px"></a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a style="float: left; margin-right: 12px;" href="https://twitter.com/BalanceCoffeeUK" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Twitterwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a style="float: left; margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.pinterest.com/balancecoffee" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Pinterestwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution also works and upvoted

Comment: This is the modern solution